# How to use xmlns declarations with XPath in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri, xml-namespaces

I'm using Nokogiri::XML to parse responses from Amazon SimpleDB. The response is something like:

```
<SelectResponse xmlns="http://sdb.amazonaws.com/doc/2007-11-07/">
  <SelectResult>
    <Item>
      <Attribute><Name>Foo</Name><Value>42</Value></Attribute>
      <Attribute><Name>Bar</Name><Value>XYZ</Value></Attribute>
    </Item>
  </SelectResult>
</SelectResponse>
```

If I just hand the response straight over to Nokogiri, all XPath queries (e.g. `doc/"//Item/Attribute[Name='Foo']/Value"`) return an empty array. But if I remove the `xmlns` attribute from the `SelectResponse` tag, it works perfectly.

Is there some extra thing I need to do to account for the namespace declaration? This workaround feels horribly like a hack.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That XPath query looks for elements that are not in any namespace. You need to tell your XPath processor that you are looking for elements in the `http://sdb.amazonaws.com/doc/2007-11-07/` namespace.

One way to do that with Nokogiri is:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(...)
doc.xpath("//aws:Item/aws:Attribute[Name='Foo']/aws:Value", {"aws" => "http://sdb.amazonaws.com/doc/2007-11-07/"})
```

Comment: Just providing "**xmlns:**" like `doc.xpath('//xmlns:Item...` should be working too.

Answer (score 20):

I found "[Namespaces in XML](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2009/04/23/namespaces-in-xml.html)" really helpful in understanding what's going on.

Basically if you have a namespace defined via `xmlns=`, you must use a namespace in your XPath searches.

So in your case, you could do one of three things:

- Remove the `xmlns` attribute from the root `SearchResponse`. In that case your original, namespace-less XPath query will work.
- Use the default namespace in your XPath query:

  ```
  doc/"//xmlns:Item/xmlns:Attribute[xmlns:Name='Foo']/xmlns:Value"
  ```
- Define a custom namespace in the second argument of the `xpath` method  and use that in your query, as shown in hrnt's solution above.

Comment: There's a `remove_namespaces!` method [documented here](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html#method-i-remove_namespaces%21).

Comment: @RobinGower Yes, and it says `For more information on why this probably is not a good thing in general, please direct your browser to` [tenderlovemaking.com/2009/04/23/namespaces-in-xml/](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2009/04/23/namespaces-in-xml)

Comment: Both the links in the comments are outdated.  Here's an updated doc link for [remove_namespaces!](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Document:remove_namespaces!)