# I need help extracting values from xml in ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am working on personal project and using Rails to learn the framework.  The project is music based and I'm using ChartLyrics.com's API to retrieve song lyrics.  The API returns XML and I am having trouble extracting the actual lyric element from the XML.

I have installed the Nokogiri gem to help parse the XML.  The following is what I'm using to retrieve the data.  From the rails console:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(http://api.chartlyrics.com/apiv1.asmx/SearchLyricDirect?artist=michael%20jackson&song=bad))
puts doc

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetLyricResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://api.chartlyrics.com/">
  <TrackId>0</TrackId>
  <LyricChecksum>a4a56a99ee00cd8e67872a7764d6f9c6</LyricChecksum>
  <LyricId>1710</LyricId>
  <LyricSong>Bad</LyricSong>
  <LyricArtist>Michael Jackson</LyricArtist>
  <LyricUrl>http://www.chartlyrics.com/28h-8gWvNk-Rbj1X-R7PXg/Bad.aspx</LyricUrl>
  <LyricCovertArtUrl>http://ec1.images-amazon.com/images/P/B000CNET66.02.MZZZZZZZ.jpg</LyricCovertArtUrl>
  <LyricRank>9</LyricRank>
  <LyricCorrectUrl>http://www.chartlyrics.com/app/correct.aspx?lid=MQA3ADEAMAA=</LyricCorrectUrl>
  <Lyric>
     Because I'm bad (bad-bad), I'm bad, come on (really, really bad)
     You know I'm bad (bad-bad), I'm bad, you know it (really, really bad)
     You know I'm bad (bad-bad), I'm bad, you know it (really, really bad) you know
     And the whole world has to answer right now
     Just to tell you once again
  </Lyric>
</GetLyricResult>
```

I shortened the lyrics to save space.  How do I extract the `Lyric` element?  I've tried all of the following:

```
> lyrics = doc.xpath('//Lyric')
=> []

> lyrics = doc.xpath('/Lyric')
=> []

> lyrics = doc.xpath('//GetLyricResult/Lyric')
=> []

> lyrics = doc.xpath('//GetLyricResult//Lyric')
=> []

> lyrics = doc.xpath('/GetLyricResult/Lyric')
=> []
```

`lyrics` is nil everytime.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

By default, nokogiri looks for elements that are not in any namespace, but this document is namespaced:

```
doc.namespaces
#=> {"xmlns:xsi"=>"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "xmlns:xsd"=>"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "xmlns"=>"http://api.chartlyrics.com/"}
```

So you have to append the `xmlns` namespace to the tag you're searching for (you can leave out the actual URL, since [nokogiri will fill in the URL for the default namespace in for you](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2009/04/23/namespaces-in-xml.html)):

```
doc.xpath('//xmlns:Lyric')
```

Alternatively you can search using css:

```
doc.css('Lyric')
```

See also: [Why doesn't Nokogiri xpath like xmlns declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737572/why-doesnt-nokogiri-xpath-like-xmlns-declarations)

Comment: That worked!!! Thank you very much, shioyama!  PHP isn't crazy about namespaces either.  Should've known.

Comment: Namespaces are a necessary evil when dealing with complex XML. They are massive overkill for normal XML and confuse people no end. Nokogiri's use of CSS to step around the namespacing problem is a nice icing layer, and is one reason why I prefer using CSS over XPath when parsing.