# Xpath doesn't return anything in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nokogiri/Xpath namespace query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690737/nokogiri-xpath-namespace-query)

Suppose there is XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<SomeResponse xmlns="some_namespace"> 
  <Timestamp>......</Timestamp> 
  <Ack>Failure</Ack> 
  <Errors> 
    <ShortMessage>ShortMessage111.</ShortMessage> 
    <LongMessage>LongMessage111.</LongMessage> 
    <ErrorCode>1</ErrorCode> 
    <SeverityCode>Warning</SeverityCode> 
  </Errors> 
  <Errors> 
    <ShortMessage>ShortMessage222.</ShortMessage> 
    <LongMessage>LongMessage222.</LongMessage> 
    <ErrorCode>2</ErrorCode> 
    <SeverityCode>Warning2</SeverityCode> 
  </Errors>
  <!-- there might be many Errors nodes -->
  <Version>123</Version> 
  <Build>122345abt_3423423</Build> 
</SomeResponse>
```

I try to find all errors and their long and short messages using Nokogiri.

I'm doing:

```
doc = Nokogiri.XML(xml)
errors = doc.xpath("//Errors")
puts errors

errors2 = doc.xpath("//Errors//ShortMessage")
puts errors
```

and it shows nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your XML is in the namespace `some_namespace` but your XPaths don't have a namespace binding. You're essentially querying different elements than are in your XML.

Using "[Clark notation](http://www.xmlsh.org/QNameClarkNotation)", the element you're trying to get to is

```
{some_namespace}ShortMessage
```

but you're querying for `ShortMessage` in the no-namespace.

Just because there is no prefix, i.e. the namespace is the default namespace, doesn't mean you can ignore it.

Comment: Must I use it? Is it necessary?

Comment: +1 learned something new, although I'm not sure how it applies to nokogiri

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690737/nokogiri-xpath-namespace-query might be helpful, and I found this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737572/why-doesnt-nokogiri-xpath-like-xmlns-declarations which is essentially a duplicate of your question.

Comment: The same question is asked on StackOverflow nearly every day.

Answer (score 20):

If you don't want to deal with namespaces, you can use

```
doc.remove_namespaces!
```

It is Lazy (= efficient), but [it is not recommended](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2009/04/23/namespaces-in-xml.html).

Comment: I want to make it work easily. That's it.