# Nokogiri returning empty on xpath queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I get the following HTTP response body from an external service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ParcelShopSearchResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://gls.dk/webservices/">
  <accuracylevel>EXACT</accuracylevel>
  <parcelshops>
    <PakkeshopData>
      <Number>97853</Number>
      <CompanyName>7-Eleven Artillerivej</CompanyName>
      <Streetname>Artillerivej 50</Streetname>
      <Streetname2>Pakkeshop: 97853</Streetname2>
      <ZipCode>2300</ZipCode>
      <CityName>København S</CityName>
      <CountryCode>008</CountryCode>
      <CountryCodeISO3166A2>DK</CountryCodeISO3166A2>
      <Telephone>-</Telephone>
      <Longitude>12.5835</Longitude>
      <Latitude>55.6643</Latitude>
      <OpeningHours>
        <Weekday>
          <day>Monday</day>
          <openAt>
            <From>00:00</From>
            <To>24:00</To>
          </openAt>
          <breaks />
        </Weekday>
        <Weekday>
          <day>Tuesday</day>
          <openAt>
            <From>00:00</From>
            <To>24:00</To>
          </openAt>
          <breaks />
        </Weekday>
        <Weekday>
          <day>Wednesday</day>
          <openAt>
            <From>00:00</From>
            <To>24:00</To>
          </openAt>
          <breaks />
        </Weekday>
        <Weekday>
          <day>Thursday</day>
          <openAt>
            <From>00:00</From>
            <To>24:00</To>
          </openAt>
          <breaks />
        </Weekday>
        <Weekday>
          <day>Friday</day>
          <openAt>
            <From>00:00</From>
            <To>24:00</To>
          </openAt>
          <breaks />
        </Weekday>
        <Weekday>
          <day>Saturday</day>
          <openAt>
            <From>00:00</From>
            <To>24:00</To>
          </openAt>
          <breaks />
        </Weekday>
        <Weekday>
          <day>Sunday</day>
          <openAt>
            <From>00:00</From>
            <To>24:00</To>
          </openAt>
          <breaks />
        </Weekday>
      </OpeningHours>
    </PakkeshopData>
  </parcelshops>
</ParcelShopSearchResult>
```

Yet, if I perform the following query, it returns `[]` even though it clearly should return `EXACT`

```
doc      = Nokogiri::XML(response_body)
accuracy = doc.xpath('//accuracylevel').try(:text)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737572/why-doesnt-nokogiri-xpath-like-xmlns-declarations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Namespace issues.

```
doc.xpath('//xmlns:accuracylevel', doc.collect_namespaces)
```

or, more explicitly,

```
doc.xpath('//webserv:accuracylevel', { webserv: "http://gls.dk/webservices/" })
```

Comment: Thank you Amadan, that helped me as well!! 

Is there a way to put that setting for using a Namespace in a global way so that I don't need to use that syntax for every single XPATH call?

Comment: @mickael Just collect namespaces in a variable and `doc.xpath("...", ns)`, it's really not a big deal

Comment: I didn't seem to need those namespaces from my end (I think), so I saw it working doing this as well... doc.remove_namespaces!

Comment: @mickael It works as long as namespaces are not needed. But imagine a document with movies and actors, each with `name` element; if you remove namespaces you might not be able to pick them apart. Removing namespaces is like throwing out the inconvenient first aid kit from your car because it is useless to the healthy you. (I'm playing a bit of devil's advocate here: if you know your data and know you won't get into a naming collision, I'm totally for removing namespaces.)

Comment: >>into a naming collision. Nice one... many thanks for thinking about that example. Really good point!. No, I don't know our data, we're just starting to use this API... let me go through it a little bit further, but failing to understanding it. Yeah, I prefer your 1st solution then to avoid possible future problems.

Thanks for the help mate!